# Can't change mappedfile to false in Apache Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to run a Java Webb Application using Apache Tomcat 8.5 through my Netbeans IDE. However, one of the functions in the jsp files has a large file size that exceeds the 65535 byte limit for Tomcat.

To combat this, I tried going into Tomcat's web.xml file and changing the mappedfile param value to false, as seen below.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

However, when I restarted the server and ran the program again, the error persisted. Confused, I checked the web.xml file again, only to find that the mappedfile param had gone back to true. As seen below.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

I tried over and over again, and every time the value keeps reverting back to true when I start up the server again. I couldn't find anybody else talking about this error when I looked it up, so I'm not sure how to fix this. What should I do to make sure it stays false?

EDIT:
This is the error i'm getting when I try to run it in its current state.

```
An error occurred at line: [237] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\work\Catalina\localhost\vendor-portal\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\views\SAA\AddNewSaaForm_jsp.java]
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [237] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\work\Catalina\localhost\vendor-portal\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\views\SAA\AddNewSaaForm_jsp.java]
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:350)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:597)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:383)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:331)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.hbc.vp.context.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If a single _method_ is larger than 64 kB I believe you are out of luck.  Split it in multiple methods.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't know for zure what's making it happen. I'm just trying to change mappedfile to false and it won't let me

Comment: If you deploy a war file you must change the file inside

Comment: [1] You have described what you believe is the core problem, but you haven't shown the evidence. Update your question to provide the _exact error message_ (using copy/paste) that you are getting from Tomcat, and also the stack trace (if there is one). I realize your actual concern is the parameter value being ignored, but it will still be helpful to see the underlying error. Also state your versions of Java and NetBeans. [2] This may be of interest: [_jspService is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/jspService-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit-td5071812.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, it's actually exactly as described, Netbeans changes in web.xml and sets mappedfile to true...

My solution is (for now) to first start tomcat manually outside Netbeans and just execute run on the webapp from within Netbeans.

I am running Netbeans 12.6, (various tomcat versions)

openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).